# random sampling from a large raster using clusterR

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

I need to take a 5% random sample from a very large raster and return a new raster. I am trying to use `sampleRandom` from the `raster` package, but the process is very slow (I only have 8GB RAM on my machine, running 64-bit R).  The raster has been cropped/masked to match an irregularly shaped study area boundary, as well - so has NA values in the rectangular extent around the polygon boundary and some internal NA values - I'm trying to sample only from the non-NA values. I've tried both sampling 5% and reversing that to sampling 95% - both ran for >2 hours without producing a result, at which point I terminated the process.

I am trying to speed it up by running it in parallel using the `clusterR` command, but I'm new to both the `sampleRandom` command and to using `clusterR`. My code runs, but I get all of the non-NA pixels returned, so the sample doesn't seem to working.  Is this a problem with my code or is it that `sampleRandom` can't run with `clusterR`?

Here is a description of my raster layer:

```
conv.mod
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 23828, 19095, 454995660  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 56, 56  (x, y)
extent      : -1220192, -150872, 87580, 1421948  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=44.75 +lat_2=55.75 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\GIS\carbon_cows\Intact\conv_mod.tif 
names       : conv_mod 
values      : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

And here is the code I have tried:

```
library(raster)
library(parallel)

tot<-cellStats(conv.mod,'sum', na.rm=TRUE) #get the total pixels in conv.mod
sampsize<-tot * 0.05 #calculate how many pixels would represent 5% 
removeTmpFiles() #clear some memory

numcores<-detectCores() -1

start<-Sys.time()

beginCluster(numcores)
cl<-getCluster()
clusterExport(cl,"sampsize", envir = .GlobalEnv)
conv.perc <- clusterR(conv.mod,sampleRandom,args=list(size=sampsize,na.rm=TRUE,asRaster=TRUE))
endCluster()

end<-Sys.time()
difftime(end,start)
```

Here are the total non-NA cells in the original raster layer:

```
tot<-cellStats(conv.mod,'sum', na.rm=TRUE)
tot
105193858
```

and the number that should be a 5% sample:

```
sampsize<-tot * 0.05
sampsize
5259693
```

But, the resulting raster has the same number of non-NA pixels as the original raster:

```
tot_convperc<-cellStats(conv.perc,'sum',na.rm=T)
tot_convperc
105193858
```

I've also tried reversing the sample size calculation and running `sampleRandom`, so that I'm requesting a 95% sample. But, I get the same result.

I'd appreciate any help in understanding why this code is not running as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I was able to take advantage of this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/random-sampling-of-raster-using-r and the reply by whuber.

The following code solved my problem, without the use of a cluster:

```
col.conv <- ncol(conv.mod)
row.conv<-nrow(conv.mod)
r<-conv.mod
start<-Sys.time()
r[runif(col.conv*row.conv) >= 0.95] <- NA # Randomly *unselect* 5% of the data

end<-Sys.time()
difftime(end,start)
```

That code ran in ~3 minutes, as opposed to over an hour for putting the `simpleRandom` code in the `clusterR` command.  I still wonder why `simpleRandom` was not actually taking a sample and also why this new code is so much more efficient, but happy to have the problem solved.

Comment: You should accept your answer, then the question appears as solved.